# Best or recommended R package for logit and probit regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression

Could somebody please recommend a good R package for doing logit and probit regression? I have tried to find an answer by searching on Google but all the links I find go into lengthy explanations about what logit regression is, which I already know, but nobody seems to recommend an R package.

Thanks in advance.

Jerome Smith

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless you have some very specific or exotic requirements, in order to perform *logistic* (*logit* and *probit*) regression analysis in `R`, you can use standard (built-in and loaded by default) `stats` package. In particular, you can use `glm()` function, as shown in the following nice *tutorials* from UCLA: [logit in R tutorial](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/logit.htm) and [probit in R tutorial](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/probit.htm).

If you are interested in *multinomial logistic regression*, [this UCLA tutorial](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/mlogit.htm) might be helpful (you can use `glm()` or packages, such as `glmnet` or `mlogit`). For the above-mentioned very specific or exotic requirements, many other R packages are available, for example `logistf` (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/logistf) or `elrm` (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/elrm).

I also recommend another nice [tutorial on GLMs](http://data.princeton.edu/R/glms.html) from Princeton University (by Germán Rodríguez), which discusses some modeling aspects, not addressed in the UCLA materials, in particular *updating models* and *model selection*.